# Что такое "libMobileGestalt"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Обновился до iOS10.3 и Xcode 8.3, начали вылезать в логе такие сообщения:

`libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 4456 (GameName) does not have sandbox access for fr7QaeyWLUvLjeuEK44hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled`

`libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)`

Но я понятия не имею что за `libMobileGestalt` такое, за что оно отвечает и где вообще используется (пытался через поиск искать).

Может кто подскажет что это такое, и как отключить?

Comment: Эта библиотека позволяет вытаскивать всякие уникальные идентификаторы приложения, девайса и т.д.
Вот ссылка на вики с кратким описанием.
http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/LibMobileGestalt.dylib